# get drawable from assets xml file

Tags: android

I have a background **xml** desc file in **assets** folder, how can i get the **drawable** obj?
xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_focused="false">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#2b2c2d" android:endColor="#404142" android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#2b2c2d" android:endColor="#404142" android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the file in drawable folder and you can get it from there as R.drawwable.filename(through code) and @drawable/yourfilename(through XML).

Generally, You should not place shape.xml files in assets folder. In assets folder we generally place custom fonts, audio file,video file etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, you can set the drawable as the background like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_name_without_the_.xml"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: can't use because he has file is assets folder rather than drawable folder.